# Elastic4s dependency to org.elasticsearch, can I get rid of it?

Tags: sbt, elastic4s

I just realized that elastic4s has a dependency to org.elasticsearch, and that dependency is downloading 20 Mb of library.

For what I have seen in the github repo for elastic4s there are 66 references to the package org.elasticsearch in the code. Nevertheless as far as elastic4s is a client, I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of it of this dependency, or at least make it less heavy.

Any thoughts on this are welcome?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic4s needs the elasticsearch jar as it is essentially a Scala DSL over the top of the Java client. In order to remove the 20mb of dependencies, we'd need the Elasticsearch team to decouple the server from the client and release those as seperate jars (if that's feasible, as a transport client acts as a node, and I imagine shares a lot of code).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and congrats for the work done in elastic4s, its working really smooth for us.